# How to set OnMapReadyCallback to my MapView instance?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a Google Map API provided `MapView` in my layout:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/map_view"
...
/>
```

In my Fragment, I implements `OnMapReadyCallback`:

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    // onCreate, onCreateView are not showing here but I have them.

   @BindView(R.id.map_view)
    MapView mMapView;

   // this is the method form the interface I am implementing.
   @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d("MyFragment", "map ready!");
    }
}
```

As you can see above, I have overriden the `onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)` because I am implementing the `OnMapReadyCallback` interface.

But, How can I set the listener for `mMapView` to listen to map ready event?

I tried `mMapView.setOnMapReadyCallback(this)` but there is no such method in `MapView`.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
getMapAsync(OnMapReadyCallback callback)
```

Eg, in your case

```
mMapView.getMapAsync(this);
```

you can find the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView)